# Calculation Error: A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to show this year store count based on to date and from date.The following code is throwing this error when i am placing this column in table.

```
ThisYearStoreCount =
IF (
    [DateDiff] > 365,
    0,
    IF (
        DATESBETWEEN ( WUSA_CAL_DIM[End_Date], [From_Date], [To_Date] ),
        DISTINCTCOUNTNOBLANK ( WUSA_STORE_DIM[Store Code] )
    )
)
```

Comment: The reason you are getting the error: DATESBETWEEN returns a table of dates. More generally, you are on a wrong path with this function, it does not test if your date is between From/To dates, it generates a list of dates between them.

Comment: So what do you suggest ?It should always show between to date and from date

Comment: I suggest to post an image of your data model, DAX code for all measures involved, and describe an example of the desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

@RADO is spot on,

If I understand your logic, something like this should work.

```
ThisYearStoreCount =
IF (
    [DateDiff] > 365,
    0,
    IF (
        [From_Date] >= WUSA_CAL_DIM[End_Date] 
        && [To_Date] <= WUSA_CAL_DIM[End_Date]
        && WUSA_STORE_DIM[Store Code] <> BLANK(),
        1
    )
)
```

That error *usually* means that you're using a function that returns a set of data, in a column context ( column contexts only allow a **single** value to exist per row ).

I'm reading between the lines a little bit, but the new column formula above will check if the end date is between the From_Date and To_Date before allowing the number 1 through.

Then you can just add the ThisYearStoreCount to any visual and it will sum wherever appropriate.

Your existing code should work as a measure ( instead of a column ) *I think* but it's impossible to tell without more information.